# Bootstrap Toggle still displaying as a checkbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement a toggle switch using http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

I have added the following into my page:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

and simply implemented the toggle switch using:

```
<input id="toggle-demo" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-demo').bootstrapToggle()
})
</script>
```

Also, here's my bundle config:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

However, it still displays as a checkbox and not the toggle switch, any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: does it show any error on console ?

Comment: @mrid nope, there are no console errors.

Comment: might be a stupid question, but you did initialize the plugin, right ?

Comment: @mrid what exactly do you mean?

Comment: i mean have you initialized the plugin correctly ( ` $('input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapToggle();` )

Comment: @mrid I have added in my code which demonstrates this - sorry I forgot to include it initially.

Comment: @mrid thank you - you made me realise that by jquery wasn't being picked up for some strange reason to do with script rendering, I have fixed this now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131280/discussion-between-mrid-and-james).

Answer (score 1):

Why go for a plugin when you can build your own with a little code ?

```css
#foo:checked::before,
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    margin-left: 100px; line-height: 30px; height: 27px; cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#foo:checked,
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: ""; width: 94px; height: 27px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/391082/sprite2.png) -56px 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-position: -3px 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover::before {
    background-position: -50px 0;
    border-right: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    width: 93px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:hover::before {
    background-position: -9px 0;
    border-left: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    width: 93px;
}
```

```html
<input id=test type=checkbox value=test checked>
<label for=test>Label</label>
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks great! I've just tried this out of curiosity, but once again only a checkbox is displayed and not the toggle switch and I cannot figure out why!

Comment: @mrid if you get rid of the `hover` state the stuttering goes away when toggling the on/off state.

Comment: yea @Press, I had added hover to make it look more like a button, but then realized it was better without it :D